# Broadcast minimum value from a specific processor

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I have 4 Processors (p0,p1,p2,p3) each of which has an array of values:

```
int i;
srand(time(NULL))
float *d= malloc(5, sizeof(float));
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  d[i] = (float) rand();
}
```

My goal is that each processor finds the minimum element of its array locally, `p_min`, and thus among all of the processors we pick the minimum one, i.e. `min(p0_min, p1_min, p2_min, p3_min)`, and send it to all processors. I use the following steps:

1. Every processor sends its local min to the root (here it is `p0`).
2. The root finds the *global* minimum element among all of them.
3. Thus, the processor that has the global min element should broadcast it to others as.

My question is: how does root, p0, notify the one that has the global min to broadcast its value in this case? I use the following way but I am sure if it is reasonable!

```
if(p_id == 0){
    for ( i = 1; i < P; ++i) {
        MPI_Recv(min[i], 1, MPI_FLOAT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
    p_id = find_min(min, 4);

}else{
    MPI_Send(&min, 1, MPI_INT,0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

MPI_Bcast(&p_min, 1, MPI_FLOAT, p_id, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you propose does **not** work. The root of a `MPI_Bcast` must be the same on all ranks, `p_id` is not. Besides I am very confused with your use of different variables and `find_min`.

There is a collective operation that does all in one step, `MPI_Allreduce`:

```
MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, &min, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_MIN, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

After this call, `min` will be the same on all ranks, the minimal of all values of `min` before the call.

Note: `MPI_IN_PLACE` is a special indicator to read and write to the same buffer.

Comment: Thank you for introducing MPI_Allreduce. `find_min` is just a function that finds the index of min value where each index represents a processor id.